# JQuery Slider is not Showing in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

[image: Here is the page I get]I am new to Handlebars/Jquery and have been trying to test this `https://jsfiddle.net/aLr8q3nf/`

When I try to show/hide the sliders using plain HTML and it's working fine, however when I try to test the same functionality using .hbs/node.JS does not work for me. When I click the button the function is being called (verified by showing up the alert;) but it does not show/hide the sliders for me not sure what am I doing wrong.

Can someone please guide me where to look?

Here is my Style.css

```css
       #box {
  display: none;
      top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Here is my index.hbs

```
<html>
```

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="roundslider.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    showBox = function () {
        $('#box').toggle();
        alert("Test");


    }
        $('#slider').roundSlider({
            sliderType: "min-range",
            value: 23,

            svgMode: true,
            rangeColor: "#03a9f4",
            pathColor: "#ececec",
            borderWidth: 0,

            editableTooltip: false,
            handleShape: "dot",
            radius: 120,
            width: 15
        });
    
</script>
```

```
<form>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>

    <button onclick="showBox();">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, Just plain HTML page. Added the page.

Comment: JavaScript and jQuery won't behave any differently on the same document whether it comes directly from an HTML file or the HTML is generated via Handlebars. I would check the document source to see what it is different between your static file and your server-generated one. Also, I would confirm that your static assets - your .js files - are accessible at the URLs you've specified in your `src` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, You are right. I just moved the function just below the <button> tag and it worked. I but not sure why though.

Comment: It is because your script was executing - and looking for the element with the id "box" - _before_ the #box element was available in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone looking for help just moved the function as below and it worked.

```js
<br><br>
<button onclick="showBox()">Click</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
     
window.showBox = function () {
    $("#box").toggle();
}


$("#slider1").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    value: 23,
    
    svgMode: true,
    rangeColor: "#03a9f4",
    pathColor: "#ececec",
    borderWidth: 0,
    
   editableTooltip: false,
  handleShape: "dot",
  radius: 20,
  width: 5,
});
    </script>
```